# How to get the link that produces a 404 error into a variable? (No Wordpress, No Magento)

Tags: javascript, php, http-status-code-404

can anyone tell me (or givew me a example) how can I get the link (string) that produces a 404 error into a variable using Javascript or PHP.

Thank you all.

Ps. I don`t use Magento or Wordpress

Comment: a 404 error, means that the site was not found.... can you specify what you're trying to do? eventually post a piece of code, demonstrating what you have tried or are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP-404 could also be issued if you don't have the mimetypes set for the filetype as well.
More information for this question would be helpful, like what you are doing that is causing the error, ie. clicking a link.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
in the .htaccess file I put:
ErrorDocument 404 /SOMEPATH/EXCEPTION.php

and in the exception.php:
$myvar = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

This shows me the string.

Thanks.